# Activiti BPMN Editor - Multiple parallel User Tasks

Tags: activiti, bpmn

My example below shows a fairly simple process **with a twist**.

The scenario given in the image below is designed so that an admin user can:

1. Create a number of users using the *Create User* form
2. Add one or all of the created users to a group
3. Save the information for all created users

[image: Example Process]

This works fine for one user, but I need the ability to create n instances of the *Create User* form and have each one follow the path for the rest of the process.

I thought I might be able to do this by using Parallel gateways to spawn new instances of the *Create User* form on the same process. But this doesn't seem to work as expected, It just overwrites the first instance of *Create User* in the process.

---

is this design possible? Am I missing something? Im aware that you can make the forms *Asynchronous* but this also does not appear to work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Executions model supports what you want, but variables model is a bit off.

Nevertheless you can separate variables and forms through call activiti subprocesses. Forms data will be separated.